# Unable to change labels when I plot NMF rank survey in R

Tags: r, nmf

I am implementing an R analysis to a data-set that I have. This is the plot

[image]

Basically I would like to change Data labels. I managed to change the title but the common scripts to change label do not work.
Basically my idea was :

```
#---Requested Edit with the Reprex
#Generating a random matrix
and.mat <- matrix(rnorm(2000),100,20)
#Shuffling the generated matrix 
Random.mat <- randomize(and.mat)
#non negative matrix factorization
real.estim <- nmf(and.mat,2:10,nrun=30,seed = 123456,.options='t')
#....................
shuffled.estim <- nmf(Random.mat,2:10,nrun=30,seed = 123456,.options='t')
plot(real.estim,shuffled.estim, main = 'NMF rank survey : Comparison between 
Real and Shuffled Data', 
xlab =' Real Data', ylab =' Shuffled Data')
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What "data labels" specifically are you trying to change? Also it's unclear exactly what function is running. You are calling `plot()` which usually draws with base graphics but your output looks like `ggplot` so there probably is an overloaded method going on here. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I am basically following what is suggested to do in CRAN. They use plot since it appears that nmf package embed something that makes plot to produce that graphic. If you look up above in the right corner you will see 'Data'. Below the two labels that I want to change.However I will give to you a reproducible example, but it does not change so much from what I have already provided.